# Storybook stories disappear when hot module reloading occurs

Tags: storybook

When I edit a component and hot module reloading occurs then all the other stories with the same title disappear. The only one still there is the story for the component that I just edited.

In component1.stories.tsx:

```
import * as React from 'react';

import Provider from './provider';
import Component1Component from './component1';

export const Component1 = () => {
  return(
    <Provider>
        <Component1Component />
    <Provider>
  )
}
export default {
  title: 'Components',
};
```

In component2.stories.tsx:

```
import * as React from 'react';

import Provider from './provider';
import Component2Component from './component2';

export const Component2 = () => {
  return(
    <Provider>
        <Component1Component />
    <Provider>
  )
}
export default {
  title: 'Components',
};
```

So in the above example if I edit component1.tsx then the story for component2.tsx disapears.

In my package.json

```
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/addon-info": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/addon-storysource": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/addons": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/react": "^5.3.19"
    "react-storybook-addon-props-combinations": "^1.1.0",
```

Answer (score 1):

Per this Github issue comment:

https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/7493#issuecomment-514508328

Stories should not have duplicate titles. Try changing your titles to reflect the names of the different components.

This issue was apparently fixed in this PR:

https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/pull/7542